# Laravel - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

Tags: laravel

Good evening,

When I try to log in with the auth of Laravel, I get this error :

TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67 
-- version Laravel 5.1

I note that I have already put this in first place in the form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

What I don't understand is why it doesn't happen when I run the code in localhost. That happens only on a server.

If you need some code, I can put it here. But I don't know at all where the problem is for now.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe try: php artisan key:generate on server

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your code, try replacing your

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

with

`{{ csrf_field() }}`.

If that does not work, try the following in command line.

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

restart your local server,and the boot it with,

```
php artisan serve
```

this should do the magic